# how to stop the fadein and fadout repeating over multiple hovers?

Tags: jquery, popup, mouseover

fadein and fadout repeating  when i use multiple hover on the company names.. how can i prevent the repeatation...thanks in advance....

demo link : http://fiddle.jshell.net/nikhilvkd/77WPz/

```
$(function(){
            $(".aa").hover(function(){
              $(this).find(".aa-over").fadeIn();
            }
            ,function(){
              $(this).find(".aa-over").fadeOut();
            });        
        });
        $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
            $('.aa-over').css({
               left:  e.pageX + 20,
               top:   e.pageY
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to clear the animation queue before starting a new one by using `.stop(true)`

```
$(function () {
    $(".aa").hover(function () {
        $(this).find(".aa-over").stop(true).fadeIn();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find(".aa-over").stop(true).fadeOut();
    });
});
$(document).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
    $('.aa-over').css({
        left: e.pageX + 20,
        top: e.pageY
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/77WPz/1/)

Comment: @Krish Glad to help..! And try to accept this answer, if it helped you in solving your issue.. :) It is not a compulsion.. :)

Comment: i had accepted the answer but it failure bcoz that time was a time limit for acceptance.Now i give u...happy :D

Comment: @Krish "Give u Happy"...ending?  Good on ya ;-)  Great answer Raj